# TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined at new DataSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Cloud Function to listen for Realtime Database triggers with Firebase. But I need to listen for my second database instance but it gives me error like this:

`functions: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined at new DataSnapshot` 
it just gives this error when my function is triggered.

(it works on deployment but not on emulator)

Here is my function:

```js
exports.checkInteractionCount = functions.database.instance("my-db-name").ref("path/to/data").onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    //console.log(change);
})
```

this is just a basic function but it gives error that I shared.

Here were error occurs:

```js
lass DataSnapshot {
    constructor(data, path, // path will be undefined for the database root
    app, instance) {
        this.app = app;
        if (app && app.options.databaseURL.startsWith('http:')) {
            // In this case we're dealing with an emulator
            this.instance = app.options.databaseURL;
        }
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you share your exact and complete Cloud Function code, and not several pieces that we cannot link together?

Comment: What appears to be is that firebase is not correctly initialized on the emulator. How are you initializing firebase?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec this is the whole code that I created for test purposes. and DataSnapshot is from source code of firebase-admin

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira my other functions and features are working correctly (even with different databases but not for triggering just retrieving data)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved it by deleting the functions folder and running firebase init again... then I just replaced the files and everything worked.