# I can't test firebase functions because of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DataSnapshot')`

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to run unit tests on firebase functions. I created functions/test/index.test.js with the intention of testing in offline mode, and the current file content is as follows:

```js
// The content is only one line.
const test = require("firebase-functions-test")();
```

When I run jest with the above file, I get the following error:

```
$ jest
 FAIL  test/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DataSnapshot')

    > 1 | const test = require("firebase-functions-test")();
        | ^
      2 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/cloudevent/generate.js:26:45)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/v2.js:25:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:26:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/features.js:4:16)
      at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/index.js:30:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:1:1)
```

Something does not seem to be set correctly before the test error. What should I do?

Comment: try updating firebase-tools and also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68510205/18265638)

Comment: I upgraded firebase-tools, deleted the functions directory as mentioned in the link, initialized it again with firebase init, and replaced the contents of the functions, but it did not work. By the way, the version of firebase-tools is `11.9.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `npm ls firebase-functions` and observed the following warning.

```
functions@ /path/to/project/functions
├─┬ firebase-functions-test@2.4.0
│ └── firebase-functions@3.20.0 deduped invalid: ">=3.23.0" from node_modules/firebase-functions-test
└── firebase-functions@3.20.0 invalid: ">=3.23.0" from node_modules/firebase-functions-test

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: firebase-functions@3.20.0 /path/to/project/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my_home/.npm/_logs/2022-09-18T09_24_27_208Z-debug-0.log
```

So I ran `yarn add firebase-functions@3.23.0`. Then, when I run the test, I no longer get the error that I got when I asked the question. Apparently, it was a version compatibility issue. Thank you.